# Ways to share common functions betweed few pages in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture

This is possibly very lame question and I lack knowledge about ASP.Net. In this case a link to an article explaining would be very welcome.

I'm working on web-site on ASP.NET with C# as codebehind. My current project involves developing few pages with very similar functionality and a many functions are the same. For example

```
private void PermissionCheck()
{
    if (null == Session["UserID"] ||
        null == Session["ProjectID"] ||
        null == Session["AssetID"] ||
        null == Session["ProjectName"])
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
    }
 }
```

Would be the same on 2 pages. Some other things are the same as well. I would like to put this into common base class. But there are other functions that don't really belong to pages at all:

```
private string GetAttachmentTempPath()
{
    return Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("AttachmentsTempFolder");
}
```

I would like to move this into `Attachment` class, but to get the physical path of the application, I need to pass in Request object into that method, which is not really nice, as it  couples `Attachment` class with `Page.Request` object.

Is there any way to move these functions somewhere else without needing to pass `Page.Request` objects around??

p.s. The appliction is huge, and there is no scope to change the entire architecture.

Comment: You could still put it in the Attachment class; the attachment class method could be: private static string GetAttachmentTempPath(string appPhysicalPath) - then you can simply call it from anywhere in your project - string attachmentTempPath = GetAttachmentTempPath(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath); This way, the code for dealing with attachments all lives in the attacment class, but you pass the actual data to it as you need it (you could even do this when you initialize the class).

Comment: Passing the object in is actually *lower* coupling than relying on HttpContext, IMHO.

Comment: btw if you are using Web site projects Microsoft's official advice is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23.aspx

Comment: @sq33G This is very interesting idea.. kinda negleted it. I'll have a think again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your permission thing you could make a base page class:

```
class BasePage : Page
{ 
   ...
   protected override OnInit() {
     // do check here
   }
}
```

Now you can implement your page like this `class MyOtherPage : BasePage { ... }`
The OnInit gets executed everytime your MyOtherPage gets loaded.

You can see a complete page lifecycle here: [Link](http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/2006/06/30/Complete+Lifecycle+Of+An+ASPNet+Page+And+Controls.aspx)

For your other problem: Consider to implement a global available static tool class

**Update**

A good approach for making things like web.config easier to access is a Singleton. In asp.net a singleton is only created once and lives until the asp worker process gets stopped . So this values are shared across the whole asp.net application. This is also good for storing data in a global context that you dont want to get out of your database or file anytime a user makes a page request (for example a version number or things like that)

**Update 2**

To access the request without passing it to every function, use this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about the inheritance. But the application has about 50 pages and every one of them will have different set of permissions/other functionality. I only lucky to have these 2 pages with the same permissions and functionality. I'll have a think how I can fit this into. Thanks. As for static tool class, there are a few, but how do I avoid passing `Request`object into that class?

Comment: @trailmax Maybe you should consider to implement a role system into your application. For your question about the request object, pls see my updated answer again.

Comment: Role system is in the list of things to do for the next year. Thanks for the update

Answer (score 2):

Base page is a good option for reusable code in Page level. Other than that for things like configuration values it's good to come up with utility classes specifically for those methods base don there type of operations.
If you need to avoid passing in `Page` object into these types of utility methods,

```
HttpContext
```

class would be handy because you can access many of the ASP.Net object through static members through this class. [HttpConext @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx)

Comment: AHA! HttpContext - that what I was missing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you have similar functions behind the page, you can use [ASP.NET WEb User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx).

You can create the functions in the usercontrol and use the control in the pages where necessary.

Have look at this article about [Web User Control in Asp.Net](http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2007/09/web-user-control-in-aspnet.html)